# Use Bootstrap to manage a single page app with pseudo pagination functions

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, bootstrap-4, single-page-application

Use case. I need a single page app (SPA), but would like to maintain a "pseudo" page functionality.  Note: content pushed to app after login via Ajax call customized for the role of the different business users...

I've got a menu:

```
<ul class="cust_style components">
    <li class="active">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#home" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="btn btn-primary collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#about" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="btn btn-primary collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#stuff" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Stuff</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I've got html div content...

```
<div class="jumbotron collapse show" id="home"> 
    <h1>Home Page Content</h1>
    <p> Blah, blah, blah...</p>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron collapse" id="about">
    <h1>About...</h1>
    <p>One, two, three...</p>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron collapse" id="stuff">
    <h1>Stuff...</h1>
    <p>Data. Data. Data....</p>
</div>
```

Obviously each of these jumbotron div's represents a single 'page' for display. I want to display these one at a time, according to the user's menu selection.

Unfortunately, the bootstrap collapse functioning is a simple toggle. Bootstrap collapse adds or delete the `show` class tag to an element.  Click a menu item to display linked content, click the same menu item to toggle the content display off... works great, but that's not exactly what I want... I want a single menu click to toggle bootstrap collapse --> `show` visible AND toggle the rest of the items to --> collapse (hidden).

I guess I could remove class `show` from every jumbotron element each time any menu selection is made, but that would adversely affect the 'native' bootstrap collapse data-toggle function of the menu selection that I want to turn on.

Can the Bootstrap collapse tooling be used as a simple menu controller?

Other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the [Bootstrap Tabs Navigation tool](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior) was a much better call here.  For more info on Tab navigation, from the link here scroll down to `And with vertical pills.`

Code extract:

```
<div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#about" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">About</a>
    <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#stuff" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Stuff</a>
</div>
```

and the page content...

```
<div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Home Page Content</h1>
            <p> Blah, blah, blah...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="about" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>About...</h1>
            <p>One, two, three...</p>   
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="stuff" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Stuff...</h1>
            <p>Data. Data. Data....</p>                 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Much better nav controller tool...  No extra javascript required.

[Github repo: Bootstrap-SPA-Sidebar-Menu](https://github.com/zipzit/Bootstrap-SPA-Sidebar-Menu)